# What's a better way to put clothes in a drawer?

Tags: home, clothing

Usually I fold my clothes and then stack them according to their type. The result looks something like the following:

[image] [source](http://www.uniquebedroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Nursery-Storage-Capacity-Interior-Design-clothes-Drawer.jpg)

But this doesn't really work very well, as it's more difficult than I'd like to see what's in each stack and when I get something out that's *not* at the top of the stack is can mess up the folds of the others in the stack.

I've tried rotating the stacks 90 degrees (so that the bottom of the fold for all of them is visible) like the following, but this only seems to work well when the stack fills up the drawer. When I've worn enough of the clothes so that it's not very full, they seem to slide and get more disheveled than I'd like them to.

[image] [source](http://www.babykerf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/IMG_0947_thumb.jpg)

What can I do to fix this sliding around? Is there a better way of putting clothes in a drawer that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Scared me there. Thought you were asking for a better way of [putting clothes in a dishwasher](http://xkcd.com/1066/ "the mouseover text").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roll the clothes and then place them vertically. This will help you see  what clothes are what and stay organized.

- Wrapping rubber bands around the clothes helps them stay folded.
- You can use CD cases(as dividers) in a rectangular box to make them stay up.

***And another way to address the extra room problem:***

Besides this take some books or other "space Fillers" and put them where the clothes used to be as you remove clothing.

Taking a box and filling it with clothing items or other items and when you remove enough clothes put those in its place. This keeps clothes standing up straight vertically.

- Also, laying clothes down flat after the drawer gets empty to a certain amount, may help.

---

**Additional Info**

[WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Fold-Clothes): Basically how to fold clothes, but this only works if you have clear containers, or other storage options as shown below.

[Folding T-shirts vertically.](http://unfuckyourhabitat.tumblr.com/post/30726666518/how-to-fold-a-t-shirt-vertically): Basically you fold the shirt in half so that it is a long rectangle and then you refold it into square blocks.

- [Fold all of your clothes vertically](http://harvardhomemaker.com/organize-drawers-layer-clothes-vertically/)- Pants can be folded vertically by folding them in half so that the legs are touching and then folding into blocks accordingly.

[53 Seriously Life-Changing Clothing Organization Tips](http://www.buzzfeed.com/juliegerstein/life-changing-clothing-organization-tips)

> Adjustable drawer organizers keep your clothes in line.
>   [image]

A alternative to this is taking a rectangular container and putting dividers in it, these can be CD cases or other items you find helpful.

> For super-neat folded clothes or towels, install wooden shelf
>   dividers.
>   [image]

These can be made yourself or you can use a book or book end(these work better).

Take containers and put them on edge. Somewhat like this:

[image]

You can fit all these methods in a drawer if you get the right size containers and dividers. And using multiple methods really help, as well.